# CSS background image not working

Tags: css, background-image

I have a modal demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/4yk7y/embedded/result/) (fiddle)...

When it comes up, the background image for the modal window shows up. However, in this code below, you'll see I have a background image for the close window function. It's not showing up and I don't understand why. The CSS should have it showing in the top, right-hand corner.

```
.reveal-modal .close-reveal-modal {
    background: #eee url(http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/images/broken_link.png) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 100px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rbga(0,0,0,.6);
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: That `text-shadow` property is not going to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `div` has no content, so you need to add a `height` and `width`:

```
.reveal-modal .close-reveal-modal {
    background: #eee url(http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/images/broken_link.png) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 100px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rbga(0,0,0,.6);
    cursor: pointer;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    }
```

`50px` is probably too much