# Set the background image using css

Tags: html, css

I write this code to set the image for may background but i didn't get my background images what I do? Any Solution?

```css
.instantqoute{
    background:url('images/services/Chrysanthemum.jpg');
    }
```

```html
<br><br>
<div class="row instantqoute" >
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use an image from my local file system as background in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519388/can-i-use-an-image-from-my-local-file-system-as-background-in-html)

Comment: Or, possible duplicate of [CSS background image not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18767969/1016716). Note: not dupehammering, since we don't know what the actual problem is yet.)

Answer (score 2):

All else being equal, and assuming your URLs are correct:

There is no content inside the div. There is no explicit height set on it. It therefore has a computed height of `0`. This provides no area for the background to be painted on.

It needs a height. Give it one by putting some content in it or setting the `height` or `min-height` property.

Comment: I want to retrieve image from my local pc folder but i didn't get the image

Comment: I quote from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519388/can-i-use-an-image-from-my-local-file-system-as-background-in-html): "It seems you can provide just the local image name, assuming it is in the same folder...", maybe you should give the complete path, example: D:\directory\image.png

Comment: @vinaykapoor — Your comment suggests you didn't read beyond the first line of my answer. Read the rest of it.

Answer (score 1):

please give height and width to `.instantqoute`. 
Background image not loading because div is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL and add height and width to your div.

```
<style>
  .instantqoute {
     background:url('images/services/Chrysanthemum.jpg');
  }
</style>

<br><br>
<div class="row instantqoute" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
   <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

U need to have size of this div, for example

```css
.instantqoute {
  background:url('images/services/Chrysanthemum.jpg');
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row instantqoute" >
  <div class="col-sm-12">
  </div>
</div>
```

Most common mistake is bad link
for example structure

```
-css/style.css
-js/script.js
-img/image.jpg
-index.html
```

Background is loading from css so if u give link like this `"img/image.jpg"`
Style css try to find this image in location: `"css/img/image.jpg"`
for left folder u need to type `"../"`
for example: `"../img/image.jpg"`

My london sucks

Comment: No image is viewed, I think that his URL is wrong!!

Comment: @ZiMtyth  Most common mistake is bad link
for example structure

-css/style.css
-js/script.js
-img/image.jpg
-index.html

Background is loading from css so if u give link like this "img/image.jpg"
Style css try to find this image in location: "css/img/image.jpg"
for left folder u need to type "../"
for example: "../img/image.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

> **Assuming given path is correct:**

Your div `instantqoute` does not contain any content therefore your image is not shown.

**Why?**

Since you haven't given a width and a height to the (div/img) / no content.

**Solution:**

Give height and width to the div & add content (If required).

**Next:**

If height and width given and you still cannot see the background.

**Then:**

> **Assuming given path is incorrect:**

- Is the image in the same directory as the file referencing it?
- Is the image in a directory **below**?
- Is the image in a directory **above**?

By "below" and "above", I mean subdirectories and parent directories. Relative file paths give us a way to travel in both directions. Take a look at my primitive example:
[image]

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

- Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
- Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
- Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts
  there (and so on...)
- To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep
  moving forward

Answer (score -1):

You can use `<img>` to achive this check below Add height and width to your div also check if the url to the image is correct.

```
<br><br>


   <div class="row instantqoute" style="height:200px;width:200px;"><img src='images/services/Chrysanthemum.jpg' style="height:100%;width:100%; ">
         <div class="col-sm-12">
                  </div>

   </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do like this:

```css
.instantqoute{
background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/2000x400); 
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row instantqoute" >
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I deleted all your css content except: background, height and width and still your code works fine, maybe you should remove the "extra" code, if I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: I've removed the other css